# Get text inside parent div

Tags: javascript, html, string, dom

I'm trying to get a text from an element, which isn't the first parent of the string. i.e.

```
<div id="wrp">
    <h1>
        <a href="www.something.com">this is the text I want</a>
    </h1>
</div>
```

let's say I got the div parent by `element=document.getElementById("wrap")` and now I want to get it's final text without looking inside all it's children : `h1` and `a`. just the text that I see on the site.

Is it possible? Please show me an example.

Comment: Use `element.innerText`.

Comment: using `jQuery` you can get it by using `children()` ...

Comment: Seriously?! innerText, that simple! wow :)
For some reason I was stuck on innerHTML.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use both `innerText` or [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent), but `innerText` [doesn't works on Firefox](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_html.html). So, a crossbrowser solution:

```
var text = element.innerText || element.textContent;
```

[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/qubuzohe/1/). [Interesting comparision about them](http://www.kellegous.com/j/2013/02/27/innertext-vs-textcontent/).

Comment: @FED sorry, images blocked here.

Comment: Haha that's OK. Cheerz!

Answer (score 0):

You want to chain your queries so that you get the anchor tag after you get the wrap div (assuming you will never add more divs inside the anchor tag, which would be a bit weird):

```
var wrap = document.getElementById("wrap");
var text = wrap.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].innerHTML;
```

If you take a look at the [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByTagName) article it has more examples on how to do this. Alternatively there is textContent but since you stated that you might add more elements at a later date, if they have text in them too then you end up needing to refactor:

```
var wrap = document.getElementById("wrap");
var text = document.getElementById("wrap").textContent;
```

Comment: won't element.innerText be enough?

Comment: innerText is an IE convention that some browsers do not follow. See this [article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent).